# Not able to connect MongoDB Atlas through Node.js on Ubuntu ONLY

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I am able to connect to Mongo DB through Compass and code on my local system but when I try to deploy the code to an Ubuntu server, it is giving me this error:

```
ERROR IN CONNECTING TO DATABASE Error: querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.tha.ovfl8.mongodb.net
at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (internal/dns/promises.js:172:17) {
errno: undefined,
code: ‘ENOTFOUND’,
syscall: ‘querySrv’,
hostname: ‘_mongodb._tcp.tha.ovfl8.mongodb.net’
}
```

I am quite sure that this is a problem with Ubuntu because I’ve tried running it on Windows and Mac both and it was working fine.

(I’ve whitelisted the IP and my Mongo DB is not dormant)

Can anybody please help? I’m quite new to Mongo DB atlas

Comment: Are you using the exact same connection string on all clients?

Comment: DNS knows nothing about the cluster. Is the connection url `mongodb+srv://tha.ovfl8.mongodb.net` ?

Comment: @rickhg12hs Yes

Comment: Something is wrong with DNS, presumably on the Ubuntu server.  You could try connecting without `+srv` as described in this [GitHub issue reponse](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/9489#issuecomment-730623013).

Comment: @rickhg12hs I am able to connect with +srv through Mongosh but not with code. I'll try without +srv and update soon

Comment: @rickhg12hs It is not getting connected to Mongo without SRV. No error, just gets stuck and times out

Comment: just to note, it's not enough just to replace srv on non srv. You should resolve connection string (ie parse txt and srv records) first before replacing

Comment: `I am able to connect with +srv through Mongosh but not with code` => if ***the same*** connection string to ***the same*** cluster on ***the same*** machine ***can be used*** with the shell and doesn't work with node, I would vote it's a node driver bug

Comment: _I am able to connect with +srv through Mongosh_  how?   `nslookup -type=SRV _mongodb._tcp.tha.ovfl8.mongodb.net` returns nothing, and it's exactly what the error _querySrv ENOTFOUND_ says. It's not a driver, it's just there is no such entry registered on public DNS.

Comment: _"I am able to connect with +srv through Mongosh..."_  From the Ubuntu server?

Comment: can you connect to mongodb server with mongo shell?